# Orleans - how to improve reminders precision

Tags: .net-core, actor, orleans

Which the best way to organize `Reminders` + `Timers` work?

I want to run a task with precision in a second.

As I understand I need to run a reminder with some interval. And each start of the interval will fire a timer to achieve a specific time.
But which interval of reminder should I specify to achieve two goals:

- Make a very durable solution (mitigate suddenly silo scaledown, silo fault, etc)
- To Increase the likelihood to achieve needed precision.
- Minimize timers & reminders overhead

Answer (score 0):

Reminders are for approximate times (minutes), Timers are for precise times. You can create a robust solution by combining the two.

Obviously you will need something that initially creates the grain. You will also need persistent storage for the reminders. Then create a reminder AND a timer in `OnActivateAsync()`.

In the reminder callback check for the existence of the timer, recreate it if necessary.

In the timer callback, make sure you call a grain method

```
        private async Task SnapshotTimerFired()
        {
            var me = this.AsReference<IScoobyDoGrain>();

            await me.DoSomethingForAScoobySnack();
        }
```

by making the grain call the runtime will know that grain is alive and `try` not to deactivate due to memory pressure